# Encryption SERVER using FIFO

Tags: unix

A code that must have one server and five clients.
Ten fifos and a pair of fifo for each client to communicat with the server.
The client sends a file name (it has some contents which is stored on the disc) the server reads the contents and encrypts the contents using XOR with 'a' and sends back to the client. The client then reads the contents and stores on the disc.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a fun little project. If this is entirely new to you, I suggest checking out a copy of [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 2nd Edition](http://www.apuebook.com/). It's an excellent book that covers systems programming in fantastic depth. (It's also very excellently written -- I imagine everyone could enjoy it, whether or not they care about programming. It's just that good. :)